# Android Line chart with bubble popup

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to create a line chart in Android with bubble popups on top of the datas. I tried using the MPAndroidChart library but not able to do the popup without the onClickListener.

I want to achieve the following output -

[image]

I also tried setting the marker view in the library but that also does not help.

Comment: Its possible with MPChart. Could you please show me the code snippet used?

Comment: @DonChakkappan thank you so much for your help. You are the man. I wish I could upvote you.

Comment: glad to hear from you.:)